# What does this block operator mean?

Tags: peak-detection

What does this block do? It's part of a block diagram for a RMS/Peak detector.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It symbolizes the input-output characteristic of a *half-wave rectifier*, which only passes positive input signals:

$$y(t)=\begin{cases}x(t),&x(t)>0\\0,&x(t)\le 0\end{cases}$$